# Tab Bar controller is not accessible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have created a tab based application for iphone. when the 1st tab presses a first view will present. this view contains a button, on pressing it another view loads.

Code is:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    Cities *cv=[[Cities alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cities" bundle:nil];
    cv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES];  
    [cv release];
}
```

Now problem is that this view is loading in whole screen so that I am not able to access tab bar.
I have set the frame for this view and the view is loading in this frame,
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 400);
}
 but in remaining part white screen is appearing means tab bar is not accessible.

I want that whatever will be load at any time tab bar should be always accessible.

Please help me out.

Comment: when you use presentModalTransmisionViewController that is the way it's shown a new view that does not show the tabBar(if it does not have one). if this new view has a button in the tab bar you could just call that that method .

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
cv.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Comment: ya its appearing but only during view is loading, as the view loaded, again it is in full screen.

Comment: Are you doing anything after the view is loaded?

Comment: no, only -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 400); }

Comment: If I will not do this then it is again in full screen, and if doing this then view is resizing but in remaining part instead of tab bar white screen is coming.

Comment: its the view name which is loading on button pressed and coming on whole screen hiding tab bar controller.

Comment: @Archana, Any significant customizations? I ask this because I created a sample project here to test if I could recreate it. First a Tab Bar Controller project and add a view controller subclass with XIB and used your code to load it modally. It worked.

Comment: Can you give me your mail id or skype id, I will send my code to you right now. Its very small just like test application.

Comment: send it to `danprolde@gmail.com`.

Comment: We were on different pages. I was assuming iPad. iPhone modal view controller doesn't allow any other screen elements on screen. To deal with this you can consider using a navigation controller like @Shrey suggested.

Comment: But by using navigation controller this look is not possible http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groupon/id352683833?mt=8

Comment: @Archana, it is possible. You just have to set each view controller's `navigationItem` as you need. Talking of the app above, the first image has a navigation item with a right and left bar button items. The second image has no left button item and a segmented control set as its title view. Third and fourth images show standard navigation items with fourth having a right bar button item. Fifth image is a view controller with its `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` set to `YES`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UINavigationController` inside your tabbar to dig inside your `UIViewControllers`??

for Ref : [Adding NavigationController to Tabbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW2)

do you really need a viewController Class for what you are trying to display??

if der's no core functionality being used, i think it will be much easier with `UIView`.

Happy Coding :)